# Ansible playbook to update daemon.json and restart docker on a running Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ansible

I have 5 kubernetes clusters that I need to change part of the /etc/docker/daemon.json and then restart docker.  I am planning on doing this via ansible, and those 2 steps are pretty straight forward.  The question I have is how can I accomplish this while not taking down the whole cluster with the docker restart?  I assume I would want to do this one node at a time, drain the node, then update/restart docker, wait for the node to come back online, then move onto the next node?  Not sure exactly how to accomplish that.

Comment: I would expect [`serial: 1`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#rolling-update-batch-size) is the setting you're looking for

Comment: Have you succeeded? Do you have a repository or a gist to share?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Drain the nodes and update them one by one, uncordoning the nodes as they complete.

As mdaniel mentioned in their comment you'll likely want to limit the batch size Ansible uses to one using `serial`. This means Ansible will only work on one host at a time. You can read about this in [Ansible's docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html).

You'll also want to structure your playbook in a way that it doesn't move onto the next host until all tasks are complete for the one it's working on. Maybe using [blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html).